# How to Correctly Upload Files to Google App Engine with App.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml, gcloud

I'm new to Google App Engine and am encountering problems with my app.yaml file.

I have 5 .php files that run totally fine in one local directory on localhost, but have no clue how to set up my app.yaml.

When I `gcloud app deploy`, my index.php is loaded to the website, but only that is loaded and is causing issues due to includes and dependencies on the other files that my app.yaml is not uploading.

I have 5 files, index.php, connection.php, userpage.php, transit.php, and query.php

My test app.yaml to simply upload index.php and connection.php for testing is

```
# app.yaml
runtime: php55

handlers:
- url: /
    script: index.php

- url: /index\.html
    script: index.php 

- url: /
    script: connection.php
```

I need both to be in the same folder in google cloud's website to function properly, but only index.php is uploading.

Answer (score 1):

By default, all the php files in the same root directory as the **app.yaml** file [will be uploaded](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#pure_php), you can see more information in that link. You can then import these files normally within your deployed app.

The problem in your **app.yaml** file is that you have two handlers (URL paths) linked to '/', so the second one will never be called. To fix this you can do:

```
# app.yaml
runtime: php55

handlers:
- url: /
    script: index.php

- url: /index\.html
  script: index.php 

- url: /connection
  script: connection.php
```

or

```
# app.yaml
runtime: php55

- url: /connection
  script: connection.php

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

In this example, if you add '/connection' at the end of the URL, the **connection.php** will be called.